# ASP .NET MVC/API method call only queue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There are Controller with method **OnlyOneCallPerUser**

How lock execute method for user if previous not complete?

```cs
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    public object OnlyOneCallPerUser()
    {
        //CALL START
        var userId = this.User;

        //WAIT BEFORE PREVIOUS CALL ENDED FOR userId 
        ... some code

        return true; //CALL END
    }
}
```

I try use named semaphore

```cs
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1, 1, USERID);
sem.WaitOne();
... some code
sem.Release();
```

But some times all hang on **sem.WaitOne()**

I think not runned **sem.Release()**

try - catch - finally is used

What I can use for this logic?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "not complete"? HTTP is stateless. The same user can only call the same method twice if they have 2 browsers open or if the page has some JavaScript to open a second request. Perhaps it would be better to explain what behavior you are expecting out of the application - I mean, why are you attempting to do this?

Comment: @NightOwl888 User/Users can run 1..x request at one time. All request must be call in order / queue. Sample: One user run from 3 tabs - must be synchronize "1 then 2  then 3" not "1 and 2 an 3", Two users run from 3 tabs each - must be "User1 - 1 then 2  then 3" and "User2 - 1 then 2  then 3". For User1 and User2  asynchronize but for each user synchronize. Lock call before previous call not ended

Comment: the controller could simply add the task to a queue of a separate automated service, then execute the jobs in order, one at a time. The queue could be just a table in a database. That way, if user makes multiple requests simultaneously they will simply be added to the queue and executed later. If you send the request via ajax, then the calling page can be programmed to check for updated results at regular intervals, rather than assuming the original call will return the results. Similar idea to if you had a hand-off queue for sending confirmation emails, or something.